# Insert statement for adding rows to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert values into a table but when i do that the values are not coming into the column that i expected they are coming at the bottom of the table. Please look at the image .. I want it in blank columns

```
INSERT INTO storiacloud.schl_storia_school_status_try
(no_of_orders)
select  count(otc_order_number)
from storiacloud.vw_storia_oms_orders as a
inner join 
storiacloud.schl_storia_school_status_try as b
on a.school_ucn = b.ucn
group by school_ucn;
```

i also tried update ... but it is giving me an syntax error ERROR: syntax error at or near "update"
  Position: 188

update t
^
please help

```
    ;With tbl  as
(
Select Count(1) as cnt, b.ucn 
FROM 
storiacloud.schl_storia_school_status_try b
INNER JOIN 
storiacloud.vw_storia_oms_orders a ON a.school_ucn = b.ucn 
Group By school_ucn 
) 
update t
SET no_of_orders = tbl.Cnt 
From  tbl
join storiacloud.schl_storia_school_status_try as t on t.ucn = tbl.ucn
```

[image]

Image of result data[image]

Comment: You have to use the Update command not Insert! Insert will ADD new columns. What you want is to UPDATE the existing data! **If I understand it right**

Comment: k .. i also tried update ... but don't know where to put the count ... UPDATE
  storiacloud.schl_storia_school_status_try
SET
  no_of_orders
FROM
  storiacloud.schl_storia_school_status_try
INNER JOIN
  storiacloud.vw_storia_oms_orders
    ON a.school_ucn = b.ucn
WHERE  count(otc_order_number)
  a.school_ucn = b.ucn
group by school_ucn;

Comment: Add on your question what your result data should look like.

Comment: please use the [ROW_NUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function. what is the No_of_order?

Comment: that is just a blank column created to insert the result .please let me know if you have any tips for row_number ... like how to implement ?

Comment: If you want others to understand the question better, then you need to recreate `vw_storia_oms_orders` and `schl_storia_school_status_try` tables with some sample data and then mention what you are expecting to update based on the sample data.
To recreate the table, use [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com) and select proper `sqlserver` version

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for. **This code is parse fine but not test**

```
;With tbl  as
(
Select Count(1) as cnt, b.ucn 
FROM 
storiacloud.schl_storia_school_status_try b
INNER JOIN 
storiacloud.vw_storia_oms_orders a ON a.school_ucn = b.ucn 
Group By school_ucn 
) 
update t
SET no_of_orders = tbl.Cnt 
From  tbl
join storiacloud.schl_storia_school_status_try as t on t.ucn = tbl.ucn
```

Comment: ERROR: syntax error at or near "update"
  Position: 194

update t
^